# local database PropertyChangedEventHandler

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have a question regarding `PropertyChangedEventHandler`.
should every table in my database have `PropertyChangedEventHandler` and `PropertyChangingEventHandler` ?
the code is like this:

```
   #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Used to notify the page that a data context property changed
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanging Members

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    // Used to notify the data context that a data context property is about to change
    private void NotifyPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanging != null)
        {
            PropertyChanging(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

Thanks.